# How can I convert the android resources int to a string. eg.: android.R.string.cancel?

Tags: android, android-resources

How can I obtain the string value "cancel" from this resource int: android.R.string.cancel ?

thank you

Comment: It is late but I think what you are seeking is that you want to convert resource id to string so that you can use it for mapping or any other use cases. I suggest to give your id name to view tag for example android:tag="cancel" and then use it in code like myViewOrResource.getTag() in Java or myViewOrResource.tag in kotlin. tags are strings and can be used easily.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Simply use [`Context#getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29):

```
String string = getString(android.R.string.cancel);
```

---

> I've already tried this approach but with no success... I've a class: `public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {`

A DialogFragment is not a subclass of Context, so you need to get access to a valid one (like your Activity's). Use this:

```
String string = getActivity().getString(android.R.string.cancel);
```

Or as your discovered you can use the Activity passed in `onAttach()`, but understand you can do this anywhere inside a Fragment as long as you have a valid Context to work with.

Comment: I've already tried this approach but with no success... but now I know what I was doing wrong:  I've a class:    'public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {'  and inside this class I was doing:    private String xbtAffirmativeLabel = getString(android.R.string.cancel) ;  and this is the problem, I can only do that inside a method like:    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {  thank you for your support it helped me to realize that.

Comment: Why did you use `android` before `R.string.cancel`? Just `getString(R.string.cancel)` worked for me inside `onCreateDialog` in a dialog fragment in a class that extends `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`

Answer (score 8):

As indicated here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)

```
String s = context.getString(android.R.string.cancel);
```

`context` can be the current activity, or any object inheriting the `Context` abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert any Android resource into a string.
In this example I’ve used an ‘R.color.myColor’ but it will work with any Android resource type.

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="btnDialBgColor">#00BFA5</color>
    <color name="btnDialBgColorActive">#C51162</color>
</resources>

TypedValue typedValueActive = new TypedValue();
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getResources().getValue(R.color.btnDialBgColorActive, typedValueActive, true);
getResources().getValue(R.color.btnDialBgColor, typedValue, true);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an old question, but it might help more people. What you can do is to call getIdentifier(). For that, you'll need to call it inserting after what value you want for a this variable, to make the string that you want for your resource ID. For exemple:

Your resources file:

```
R.string.cancel
```

In java:

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("cancel", "string", this.getPackageName())
println(getResources().getString(resourceId));
```

Then, in your rescourceId variable, you'll have an equivalent to: R.string.cancel. And, in println, you'll have the value correspondent of your resources string.

In Kotlin:

```
val resourceId = this.resources.getIdentifier("cancel", "string", this.packageName)
println(resources.getString(resourceId))
```

With the same explanation that I said before.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31046535)