# Get color resource as string

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

I'm trying to use `Color.parseColor()` on a color resource:

```
<color name="redish">#FF0000</color>
```

I've tried this, but it gives me the **error Unknown color**:

```
Color.parseColor(Integer.toHexString(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.redish)))
```

How do I convert the color resource to a `String` properly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you missed **#**

```
Color.parseColor("#"+Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.redish)))
```

Comment: `Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.redish)` with recent versions this worked for me.

Comment: getColor i deprecated...[more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590714/getcolorint-id-deprecated-on-android-6-0-marshmallow-api-23)

Answer (score 7):

Updated answer:

```
String colorHex = "#" + Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary) & 0x00ffffff);
```

Comment: This worked for me when the accepted answer didn't. Thanks!

Comment: The accepted answer was not working for me, but this one does! Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
String colorString=getResources().getString(R.color.redish);
```

Try this

Answer (score 2):

```
context.getResources().getColor(R.color.redish));
```

Comment: `context` needs to be there... it's within an adapter.

Comment: where you store your color xml ?

Answer (score 1):

I got a color stored in object (containing other fields). Also the colors were defined in xml file (colors.xml). 
So wanted to set the background color of textview. I did it as follows:

```
...    
String color= res.colorName; // res is an object
int c = context.getResources().getIdentifier(color,"color", context.getPackageName());
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + Integer.toHexString(context.getResources().getColor(c))));
```

If you are using the code in activity you can omit use of 'context' .

Comment: Here's another way of doing it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388493/how-can-i-convert-the-android-resources-int-to-a-string-eg-android-r-string-c/43621406#43621406