# Converting the string resources to strings

Tags: android, string, resources

I've already tried to use

```
String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
```

And I found the same theme in this article [How can I convert the android resources int to a string. eg.: android.R.string.cancel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388493/how-can-i-convert-the-android-resources-int-to-a-string-eg-android-r-string-c). But it doesn't work in my situation.

This is my code:

```
public class Film{


  private int image;
    private String name;
    private  String schedule;
    private  String description;

    public Film() {
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
       ...
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}

public class FilmList {


 public static   ArrayList<Film> getFilms(){
        ArrayList<Film>films=new ArrayList<>();
        Film film=null;

        film =new Film();
        film.setName(getResources().getString(R.string.name1));
        film.setImage(R.drawable.img1);
        film.setDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.desc1));
        films.add(film);

        film =new Film();
        film.setName(getResources().getString(R.string.name2));
        film.setImage(R.drawable.img2);
        film.setDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.desc2));
        films.add(film);

        return films
         }
    }
```

Comment: You can create resource instance in application class, and access it anywhere, because application class is live till your app is running.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to a `Context` (e.g. via an `Activity`, `Service`, `ContentProvider`, or `BroadcastReceiver`), you **cannot** get a string resource.

If you have a class that is not one of the above and it needs to get a string resource, you must either have pass a `Context` to that class so it can retrieve the resource, or pass that class an already-resolved resource.

Answer (score 0):

Make an application class and add a hold its reference in a static varialble. then you can access context anywhere in the app

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private static AppLWP instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         instance = this;
    }
 }
```

Then you can access this instance for context anywhere in the app

```
public static ArrayList<Film> getFilms(){
    ArrayList<Film>films=new ArrayList<>();
    Film film=null;

    film =new Film();
    film.setName(MyApp.instance.getResources()
    .getString(R.string.name1));
    film.setImage(R.drawable.img1);        
    film.setDescription(MyApp.instance.getResources()
    .getString(R.string.desc1));

    films.add(film);

    film =new Film();        
    film.setName(MyApp.instance.getResources()
    .getString(R.string.name2));
    film.setImage(R.drawable.img2);
    film.setDescription(MyApp.instance.getResources()
    .getString(R.string.desc2));
    films.add(film);

    return films
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, provide context to the class Film via the activity you are calling the object of Film.

If you call from Main Activity you will have to do something like this:

```
public class MainActivty extends AppCompatActivity {

private static MainActivty obj;
onCreate() {
     //usual functions
     obj = MainActivity.this;
   }
}
```

Once you have the context, simply try this:

```
String mystring = context.getString(R.string.mystring);
```

Or, if you floowed my MainActivty method:

```
String mystring = MainActivty.obj.getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
```